# Finding the smallest lipschitz constant

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Given is $f(x_1,x_2) = \sqrt {(6x_1)^2 + (9x_2)^2}$

Calculate the smallest Lipschitz constant: $L > 0$

so that: $ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq L||x-y|| $

for all $x,y\in {\Bbb R}^2$ and $||.||$ being the Euclidean norm.

So far the exercises I've been doing have only required me to calculate Lipschitz constants in $f(x)$ and  column sum norms. This is why I am totally lost here and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i differentiated the function in terms of  $x_1 , x_2$ and got

$fx = 36x / \sqrt { 36x_1^2 + 81x_2^2} $
and
$fy = \dfrac{81y}{\sqrt{81y^2+36x^2}} $

i'm swinging in the dark here. what i've usually done is i differentiated $f(x)$ and always had a value I could compare it with in order to get L. but in this exercise I don't know how to proceed

Comment: @tictac Good work; now can you try to bound the derivatives above? for instance, can you bound their denominator so you might get out $\|x-y\|$ as a coefficient?

Comment: sorry i'm really not seeing the light

Comment: @Zim should i try subtracting the two deravites from each other? $fx - fy$ ?

Comment: @tictac Not quite, so the derivative stuff is motivated by the fact that if $\sup_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2} |\nabla f(x_1,x_2)|$ exists, then it is a sharp Lipschitz constant, i.e. you've found $L$ and you're done. So finding an upper bound on the norm of your gradient is your next task -- i.e. you'll need to stack $[fx, fy]$ in a vector and see if you can bound it above.

Answer (score 0):

For shorthand, I will use the notation ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2)$ and ${\bf y}=(y_1,y_2)$. Let $L\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2\colon(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(6x_1,9x_2).$ Then $L$ is a bounded linear operator with norm $\|L\|=\|(6,9)\|=\sqrt{36+81}\approx 10.8$. Then $f$ is the composition of the Euclidean norm with $L$, i.e. $f(x,y)=\|L(x,y)\|$. By the reverse triangle inequality and properties of norms,

$$|f({\bf x})-f({\bf y})|=\left|\|L{\bf x}\|-\|L{\bf y}\|\right|\leq \|Lx-Ly\|\leq \|L\|\|x-y\|.$$

You could probably also get another bound using the fact that $\sup_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2} \|\nabla f(x_1,x_2)\|$ is a sharp Lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_{x_0}(x_1-x_0)+f_{y_0}(y_1-y_0)+O((x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2)
$$
so

$$
|f(x_1,y_1)- f(x_0,y_0)|\le \sqrt{f_{x_0}^2+f_{y_0}^2}\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}
$$

here

$$
\sqrt{f_{x}^2+f_{y}^2} = \sqrt{\frac{9 \left(16 x^2+81 y^2\right)}{4 x^2+9 y^2}} = L
$$

hence

$$
6\le L \le 9
$$

Comment: I believe this result holds only locally, due to the linearization